# How to make Codeigniter Split Search

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want codeigniter search to be match with any one word to column.

Example: Let's Say Search Query is "Fashion Outlet for Mens", Now in table column title is "Fashion Outlet" only so i want search input to be split word by word and match column.

Any Help Please

```
public function search($query) 
  {
    $q = $this->db->from('tablename')
    ->like('title',$query)
    ->get();
    return $q->result();
  }
```

Updated Question

```
public function search_query($query,$limit,$offset) 
{
    $keywords = explode(' ', $query);

    foreach ($keywords as $keyword)
    {
    $keyword = trim($keyword);
    $this->db->or_where("`title` LIKE '%$keyword%'");
    $this->db->join('table2', 'tablename.id = table2.id');
    $this->db->limit( $limit , $offset );
    $this->db->order_by('updated_on','desc');
}
$this->db->get('tablename');
return  $this->db->result();
}
```

Error Got

```
Not unique table/alias: 'table2'

    SELECT * FROM `tablename` JOIN `table2` ON `tablename`.`id` = `table2`.`id` JOIN `table2` ON `tablename`.`id` = `table2`.`id` WHERE `title` LIKE '%fashion%' OR `title` LIKE '%outlet%' ORDER BY `updated_on` DESC, `updated_on` DESC LIMIT 50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the Updated Answer for Order By Keyword Priority.

```
$keywords = explode(' ', $query);
 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('tablename');
 $this->db->join('table2', 'tablename.id = table2.id','left');
 $orderbyQry = "CASE "; 
 foreach ($keywords as $key => $keyword)
 {
    $orderbyQry.="WHEN tablename.title LIKE '%$keyword%' THEN $key ";
    $keyword = trim($keyword);
    $this->db->or_where("tablename.title LIKE '%$keyword%'"); 
 }
 $orderbyQry.=" ELSE 100 END ";
 $this->db->limit( $limit , $offset );
 $this->db->order_by($orderbyQry,'asc');
 $this->db->get();
 return  $this->db->result();
```

Comment: Thanks Almost Query Solved, But giving database error. i tried to add   $this->db->get('tablename');

Comment: Not unique table/alias: 'tablename'

SELECT * FROM `tablename`, `tablename` WHERE `title` LIKE '%fashion%' OR `title` LIKE '%outlet%'

Comment: if you are using  $this->db->get('tablename'); then remove the $this->db->from('tablename'); line

Comment: Use are using tablename twice beacuse of $q = $this->db->from('tablename'); and $this->db->get('tablename');. Use any one of them

Comment: Yes Thanks that error has gone, but i also had a join table query in it. Now that join table Not unique table/alias: 'table2' is showing. I have updated my question of new query, please help me out in that.

Comment: Is there any way to get first word of search input in like clause to be searched. Like if i search "Samsung mobile" so priority to match text should be "Samsung" keyword not "mobile",bcoz" mobile" is common name which result out all column data

Comment: If your query is solved then Please mark the question as solved. And you can make the order by clause like this..... ORDER BY case when title LIKE '%Samsung%' then 1 when title LIKE '%mobile%' then 2 ELSE 100 END ASC;

Comment: can u plz share updated code of that samsung priority search match

Comment: Thanks for marking as solved.Please find the updated answer for order by Query

Answer (score 0):

Please join the table only once, and put the limit and order_by clause out of the loop.

```
public function search_query($query, $limit, $offset) {
 $keywords = explode(' ', $query);
 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->join('table2', 'tablename.id = table2.id');
 foreach ($keywords as $keyword)
 {
    $keyword = trim($keyword);
    $this->db->or_where("`title` LIKE '%$keyword%'"); 
 }
 $this->db->limit( $limit , $offset );
 $this->db->order_by('updated_on','desc');
 $this->db->get('tablename');
 return  $this->db->result();
}
```

Comment: An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::result()

Comment: On last line $this->db->result(); this error is showing

Comment: Is there any way to get first word of search input in like clause to be searched. Like if i search "Samsung mobile" so priority to match text should be "Samsung" keyword not "mobile",bcoz" mobile" is common name which result out all column data

Comment: As I see, @Mukesh_Yadav helped you already. Great, you guys are amazing.